# Combine multiple rows into single column + Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, join, crystal-reports

I have a table 'BOIZ' with the following data

```
+-----+------+
| bid | nums |
+=====+======+
| 1   | 101  |
+-----+------+
| 1   | 103  |
+-----+------+
| 2   | 102  |
+-----+------+
| 1   | 105  |
+-----+------+
| 2   | 101  |
+-----+------+
| 2   | 115  |
+-----+------+
| 2   | 118  |
+-----+------+
| 2   | 21   |
+-----+------+
```

just want to combine the rows into single row based on 'bid' column.
if bid = 1 then

```
+---------------------+
| 101st, 103rd, 105th |
+---------------------+
```

if bid = 2 then

```
+----------------------------------+
| 102nd, 101st, 115th, 118th, 21st |
+----------------------------------+
```

I have 2 ways but wanted to know how I can do it using something like CROSSAPPLY OR PIVOT OR OTHER ways

way 1 -- working fine

```
select STUFF((select ', ' +t1.OrdinalNumber from
  (select BZ.bid,Cast(
  BZ.nums as VARCHAR(15)) + 
   CASE WHEN BZ.nums % 100 IN (11,12,13) THEN 'th' 
   WHEN BZ.nums % 10 = 1 THEN 'st' 
   WHEN BZ.nums % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd' 
   WHEN BZ.nums % 10 = 3 THEN 'rd' 
   ELSE 'th' 
   END AS OrdinalNumber from BOIZ BZ 
where BZ.bid = 2
) as t1
FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS BOXED
```

2nd way -- working fine

```
Declare @val Varchar(MAX); 
Select @val = COALESCE(@val + ', ' + OrdinalNumber, OrdinalNumber)
        From(select BZ.bid,Cast(
  BZ.nums as VARCHAR(15)) + 
   CASE WHEN BZ.nums % 100 IN (11,12,13) THEN 'th' 
   WHEN BZ.nums % 10 = 1 THEN 'st' 
   WHEN BZ.nums % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd' 
   WHEN BZ.nums % 10 = 3 THEN 'rd' 
   ELSE 'th' 
   END AS OrdinalNumber from BOIZ BZ 
where BZ.bid = 2)
 as t1 Select @val;
```

I just want to know how can I achieve this using CROSSAPPLY OR PIVOT or by some other method.

Y'all might be wondering why I want more ways. It is because I'm working on crystal reports and the above 2 queries are not supported in the SQL expression field in the crystal report . report just crashes when using STUFF() and does not support DECLARE statements.

Comment: Why not just use `STRING_AGG`?

Comment: Its not supported in my version :(   . I am using sql server version 13.0.1601.5

Comment: 13.0.1601.5? Why haven't you installed a single security update or bug fix on your instance in the last 6 years? The lastest build is 13.0.7016.1, which came out in June.

Comment: yes I agree. I'm working with some old data and told not to change anything about the server.

Comment: Are you alllowed to create some helper views on SQL server? If yes, then you can shift your functionality there and just use those views in CR.

Comment: @Arvo yes. I will test with views. Although I have tried using stored procedure but was not able to set the parameter with database table field. I cannot do application level changes but only limited to report level. if you can give me some advice regarding how to use report field dynamically as a parameter to my procedure it will be very helpful. But your usage of VIEWS gave me some idea. will test and get back here.

Comment: Using procedures with dynamic parameters in CR is generally PITA (at least for me), although we do have some such reports here (not designed by me, thereby not much help about that). You likely need procedure, which returns fixed structure recordset independently of parameter values, otherwise CR loses parameter link easily (it checks structure with null value or so). View is usually much simpler, if you can manage to bind it to real data somehow :) SQL functions unfortunately are directly not supported.

Comment: Hi @Arvo my problem has been resolved by using **views.** Thank you very much brother. you were of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PIVOT operator with this way:

```
SELECT bid, 
    CAST([1] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + COALESCE(', ' + CAST([2] AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '') +
    COALESCE(', ' + CAST([3] AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '') + COALESCE(', ' + CAST([4] AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '') +
    COALESCE(', ' + CAST([5] AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '') + COALESCE(', ' + CAST([6] AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '') +
    COALESCE(', ' + CAST([7] AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '') + COALESCE(', ' + CAST([8] AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '') AS BOXED
FROM (
    SELECT bid, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bid ORDER BY nums) AS rn, 
        CAST(nums AS VARCHAR(15)) + 
            CASE 
                WHEN nums % 100 IN (11,12,13) THEN 'th' 
                WHEN nums % 10 = 1 THEN 'st' 
                WHEN nums % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd' 
                WHEN nums % 10 = 3 THEN 'rd' 
                ELSE 'th' 
            END AS OrdinalNumber
    FROM BOIZ
) AS t
PIVOT (
    MAX(OrdinalNumber)
    FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])
) AS p
```

Comment: thank you so much. works good.